# Call an method of a class in an array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, shapes

I am having a problem with a project.

So basically what I have is a class Shape with some sub-class ( ShapeRectangle, ShapeTriangle, etc ).
In each sub-class, I got an outputShape method:
    g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());

In another class, showShapes, I got an array that contains the sub-classes.

I would like to run the method via the array.

Is there any way to do it?

EDIT:
The array in showShapes is a Shape[] array.

Here are the code of ShapeRect ( sorry, bits are in french ):
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

```
public class FormeRectangulaire extends Forme {
  public FormeRectangulaire(int x, int y, int width, int height){
    setX(x);
    setY(y);
    setWidth(width);
    setHeight(height);
    setColor(Color.RED);
  }

  public void afficherForme(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(getColor());
    g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
  }
}
```

Here is the shape:
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;

```
public class Forme {

private int x;
private int y;
private int width;
private int height;
private Color color;

/*public void afficherForme(Graphics g){
    afficherForme(g);
}*/

public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public Color getColor(){
    return color;
}

public void setColor(Color color){
    this.color = color;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}
public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}
public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}

}
```

And here is how I put each class inside the array:

```
    public void creerArrayFormes(){
    String[][] donnes = getDatas();

    if(donnes[getDatasElement()][0].equals("CARRE") || donnes[getDatasElement()][0].equals("RECTANGLE")){
        FormeRectangulaire rect = new FormeRectangulaire(Integer.parseInt(donnes[getDatasElement()][1]),Integer.parseInt(donnes[getDatasElement()][2]),Integer.parseInt(donnes[getDatasElement()][3]),Integer.parseInt(donnes[getDatasElement()][4]));

        setFormes(rect, getDatasElement());
    }

}
```

Comment: Does Shape declare outputShape as an abstract method? If not, why not?

Comment: Is the array declared as Shape[]?

Comment: If I have understook correctly, shouldn't be enought to loop through the array an call the method in each object?

Comment: The array is declared as Shape[]. And no Shape does not declare outputShape as an abstract method. I don't understand, why I should it.

Comment: Please provide some code snippet.

Comment: I could provide the code, but some bits are in french, that's why I didn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create an array object or a `List` of *SuperClass* :

```
List<Form> shapes = new ArrayList<Form>();
//List<Form> shapes = new ArrayList<>(); in JDK 7
shapes.add(new ShapeRectangle());
shapes.add(new ShapeTriangle());
//....
```

Create a loop to get the objects :

```
  for(int i = 0; i<shapes.size();i++){
      Object obj = shapes.get(i);
      if(objinstanceof ShapeRectangle){
         ((ShapeRectangle)obj).fillRect(....);
      }
      else if(list.get(i)
    }
```

Comment: But the thing is, the whole point of creating this method is to avoid doing if's and else and reduce code. I coud've just made a simple g.fillrect with some offs depending on the shapes.

Comment: You mean you have one method that `fillRect(...)` that draws a Rectangle and Triangle ?

Comment: That draws a rectangle and a method fillTri(...) inside a ShapeRect sub class.

Comment: OK, without `if-else` how would you know what to draw? or how would you know the object that you get it from the list is a *Rectangle* or a *Triangle*?

Comment: I already have an if-else that determines what shape it is and creates the correct sub-class and then places it in the array. So I would like to know re-use if-else because that would would just be repetitive no?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend adding outputShape to the Shape class. If Shape is naturally abstract (no expectation of actually creating a new Shape()) it can be abstract.

If you do that, you can just iterate over your Shape[] and call outputShape for an element. That will call the version of outputShape for the actual class of the element:

```
for(Shape s: shapes) {
  s.outputShape();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Because after that I would need to add these shapes to an JFrame...

Comment: So change what you do with the outputShape method, or add parameters to it. The key idea I'm trying to get across is that you should put in Shape the common methods that all subclasses have, and then you don't need to do a stack of ifs or switches to run the correct method.

Comment: @AraSivaneswaran: Also consider `Graphics2D#draw()` using concrete implementations of the `java.awt.Shape` interface.